# 'yum' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: centos, yum, virtual-machine

I installed CentOS 7 minimal on VirtualBox; when I type:

```
yum install net-tools
```

I get this error:

> 'yum' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Hmm, that's probably a bit too minimal. What does something like `rpm -qa | egrep 'yum|dnf'` show?

Comment: Check if `/usr/bin/yum` exists.  If not, you have a broken installation or you're not really on CentOS 7.

Comment: Even minimal installation includes `yum`.

Answer (score 2):

> 'yum' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

This is a Windows error message, you need to run your commands inside a shell in your CentOS VM, not at a Windows command prompt.

Comment: You're right I run it in cmd but using ssh

Comment: That's weird, i reboot the VM, and it's worked after that !